# Should variable references be $-prefixed in arithmetic for loops (arithmetic contexts)?

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop, syntax

All of these options below work for setting i to count.

```
count=5

for (( i=count; i>=0; i-- )); do 
    echo "$i"
done

for (( i=$count; i>=0; i-- )); do 
    echo "$i"
done

for (( i=$((count)); i>=0; i-- )); do 
    echo "$i"
done

for (( i=${count}; i>=0; i-- )); do 
    echo "$i"
done
```

Which is correct or preferred?

Comment: I'd use solution 2. For solution 3 I would replace `$((count))` with `${count}`

Comment: Thank you.  I added that as a fourth option.  Somewhere I read not to use solution 2 with the $ but I don't know if that is correct or why.  It may have been because they were doing something like i=$count-1 so someone said to use i=$((count-1)) instead

Comment: I think its the exact opposite. I would't use `$(count)` since `$()` first evaluates a variable while `${}` expands it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, **in arithmetic contexts such as `((...))` and `$((...))`, reference variables by name only, *without* the `$` prefix** (as your commands are already doing with respect to variable `$i`):

```
for (( i=count; i>=0; i-- )); do 
    echo "$i"
done
```

- Since `((...))` is an arithmetic context itself, there is no good reason to use a separate, expanding arithmetic context - `$((count))` - inside of it.
- Note that `$count` and `${count}` are equivalent, and enclosing the variable name - `count` - in `{` and `}` after `$` is only *necessary* to disambiguate the variable name from subsequent characters that can also legally be part of a variable name (which doesn't apply to your commands).
  As [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) points out, some people choose to *always* use the `${var}` form for visual clarity.

While `$`-prefixed variable references in arithmetic contexts do work, there is rarely a good reason to use them: the use of `$` introduces an extra expansion step *before* the arithmetic evaluation, which is not only unnecessary, but can result in different behavior, as explained in [rici's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43313659/45375).

The **only cases where you *need* the `$` prefix**:

- To **reference *positional* and *special parameters (variables)*** that can only ever be referenced *with* `$`: <sup>Thanks, [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici).</sup>

  - Positional parameters: `$1`, `$2`, ...
  - The count of positional parameters: `$#`
  - Special parameters: `$?`, `$$`, `$!` (there are others, but they are not generally *numeric* - see chapter `Special Parameters` in `man bash`).
- **If you need a *nonzero default value*** that you provide **via a *parameter expansion***; e.g., `${count:-2}` defaults to `2` if `$count` is unset or empty.
- If you want to **use a variable value as an *operator*** rather than operand; e.g.:
  `op='*'; echo $(( 2 $op 2 ))` - this wouldn't work with just `op`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between using `$x` and just `x` in an arithmetic context:

- `x` causes the value of `x` to be evaluated as a number. If `x` hasn't been defined, the result is 0. If the value of `x` is a valid arithmetic expression, that expression is evaluated. If it is an invalid expression, the result is a syntax error.
- `$x` causes the value of `x` as a string to be interpolated into the arithmetic expression, which will then be evaluated.

This leads to different evaluations, particularly with uninitialized variables:

```
$ unset x
$ echo $((x/2))
0
$ echo $(($x/2))
bash: /2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/2")

# Also, with incomplete expressions
$ x=42+
$ echo $((x 7))
bash: 42+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
$ echo $(($x 7))
49
```

In both cases, I prefer the behaviour associated with the unadorned use of the variable name. Consequently, I recommend its consistent use in arithmetic expressions unless you have a really good reason not to (in which case, you probably should quote the expansion to make it clearer what your expectation is.)

Comment: Great explanation. It may be worth pointing out that using quoting in arithmetic contexts appears to only work in Bash v4.4 and above; for instance, `x=4; echo $(( "$x" / 2 ))` fails in older versions with a syntax error.
A conceivable use case for using a `$`-prefixed reference is to use a variable value as an _operator_ rather than an operand.

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid `$((count))`, as this creates an unnecessary arithmetic evaluation step.  The other ones have different syntax, but the exact same semantics.  I would use the first one, for no better reason than it being shorter.

I suggest the still equivalent (in its result), but shorter :

```
for (( i=count+1; i-->1 ;)); do 
    echo "$i"
done
```

I have always liked that one, because it visually says "i goes toward 0".

Comment: @mklement0 I fixed the bug, I usually use this to iterate over zero-based array, my mistake.  As for this being obscure, well, in a sense it is, but I find it very intuitive on a visual level (less so with arrays beginning at 1, though, obviously), but I agree it is not something you see often.

Comment: Bash arrays _are_ `0`-based, so now your code is missing the iteration for index `0`. As for `-->`: can I suggest that you point out directly in your answer that `-->` is not a special operator, but two separate operators joined without whitespace?  (I didn't down-vote, btw.)