# Filter a very large, numerically sorted CSV file based on a minimum/maximum value using Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I'm trying to output lines of a CSV file which is quite large. In the past I have tried different things and ultimately come to find that Linux's command line interface (sed, awk, grep, etc) is the fastest way to handle these types of files.

I have a CSV file like this:

```
1,rand1,rand2
4,randx,randy,
6,randz,randq,
...
1001,randy,randi,
1030,rando,randn,
1030,randz,randc,
1036,randp,randu
...
1230994,randm,randn,
1230995,randz,randl,
1231869,rande,randf
```

Although the first column is numerically increasing, the space between each number varies randomly.  I need to be able to output all lines that have a value between X and Y in their first column.

Something like:

```
sed ./csv -min --col1 1000 -max --col1 1400
```

which would output all the lines that have a first column value between 1000 and 1400.

The lines are different enough that in a >5 GB file there might only be ~5 duplicates, so it wouldn't be a big deal if it counted the duplicates only once -- but it would be a big deal if it threw an error due to a duplicate line.

I may not know whether particular line values exist (e.g. 1000 is a rough estimate and should not be assumed to exist as a first column value).

Comment: I like @Benjamin W. answer. OP, can we exploit the "0"s? `sed '^1[[:num:]]{3},/,/^14[[:num:]]{3}/p'` That would work even if the existing 1000 and 1400 do not actually occur. Any number between 1000 and 1999 for starting and any line between 1400 and 1499 for ending would suffice. That would of course require some regex knowledge just for calling the script...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optimizations matter when it comes to large files; the following `awk` command:

- is parameterized (uses variables to define the range boundaries)
- performs only a single comparison for records that come *before* the range.
- exits as soon as the last record of interest has been found.

```
awk -F, -v from=1000 -v to=1400 '$1 < from { next } $1 > to { exit } 1' ./csv
```

Because `awk` performs *numerical* comparison (with input fields that look like numbers), the range boundaries needn't match field values precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the numbers are increasing and unique, you can use addresses like this:

```
sed '/^1000,/,/^1400,/!d' infile.csv
```

which does *not* print any line that is outside of the lines between the one that matches `/^1000,/` and the one that matches `/^1400,/`.

Notice that this doesn't work if `1000` or `1400` don't actually exist as values, i.e., it wouldn't print anything at all in that case.

In any case, as demonstrated by the answers by mklement0 and that other guy, awk is a the better choice here.

Comment: Thanks. The lines are unique, but the first column values may not be. The real problem would be the fail state you described, where 1000 and 1400 may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `awk`, though it won't take full advantage of the file being sorted:

```
awk -F , '$1 > 1400 { exit(0); } $1 >= 1000 { print }' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash-version of the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
fname="$1"
start_nr="$2"
end_nr="$3"
while IFS=, read -r nr rest || [[ -n $nr && -n $rest ]]; do
    if (( $nr < $start_nr )); then continue;
    elif (( $nr > $end_nr )); then break; fi
    printf "%s,%s\n" "$nr" "$rest"
done < "$fname"
```

Which you would then call `script.sh foo.csv 1000 2000`

The script will start printing when the number is large enough and then immediately stops when the number gets above the limit.

Comment: Unless the range starts near the beginning of the file and is small, this will be prohibitively slow with large input. As an aside: it's generally [better not to `$`-prefix variable references in arithmetic contexts in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43312237/45375).